# Redirect subdomain to different domain using AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudfront

I'm currently going through the process of switching our domain, we'll say we're moving from olddomain.com to newdomain.com

We have all of our services hosted on AWS, and I'm having an issue with our www subdomain not properly redirecting to the new domain.

I'm trying to have [www.olddomain.com](http://www.olddomain.com) redirect to [www.newdomain.com](http://www.newdomain.com) - the strategy that I'm on currently attempting is to use an s3 static site that redirects to the new domain. Since the site/url is https, I'm also needint to put a cloudfront distribution in front.

Starting from the bottom and moving up...

1. The s3 static site url directly works fine for the redirect.
2. The cloudfront distribution (pointing properly to the s3 static site) works fine for the redirect, both on http and https.
3. I have the DNS record for [www.olddomain.com](http://www.olddomain.com) pointing at the cloudfront distribution
4. Going to [www.olddomain.com](http://www.olddomain.com) does NOT redirect, but instead tries to render our web application on a broken [www.olddomain.com](http://www.olddomain.com) (server is setup to not allow traffic from there anymore).

I've gone through a lot of different options and configuration, but it's very stange/important that the redirect works fine directly on the s3 static site as well as the cloudfront distribution, however it does not work when going to the domain that points to the cloudfront distribution. Please let me know any further details that can be supplied to help look into this issue and I'll be happy to supply them.

Answer (score 0):

The issue for me ended up being that I needed to add the alternate CNAME of [www.olddomain.com](http://www.olddomain.com) and the ssl certificate for that domain in the cloudfront settings.